# How to groupby a column and check the most occurring of value in another column and returning a dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, mode

I have a dataframe and I want to groupby a given column `cosine_group`, based on this group, I would like to get the most occurring `Amount`(**mode**). And as an out I would like to return the most occurring amount in a given group with it's description

data =

```
        description                               type    amount    cosine_group
485099454 atm wd 12140282 fcmb uyo abak atm 3       D     20000.00      1
0421209017073500 loan payment receipt               D     1625.95       0
0421209017073500 loan payment receipt               D     19931.87      0
816905417622 atm wd 10630481 uyo                    D     2000.00       2
456011516 atm wd 12140283 fcmb uyo abak atm 4       D     20000.00      1
0421209017073500 loan payment receipt               D     23160.27      0
508235027 atm wd 12140282 fcmb uyo abak atm 3       D     15000.00      1
419988664 atm wd 12140283 fcmb uyo abak atm 4       D     20000.00      1
831107336668 atm wd 10630485 uyo                    D     10000.00      2
456012171 atm wd 12140283 fcmb uyo abak atm 4       D     20000.00      1
atm wd 10630485 uyo matter                          D     10000.00      2
```

My expected output would look like this:

```
description                                       amount      cosine_group
0421209017073500 loan payment receipt             19931.87      0
456011516 atm wd 12140283 fcmb uyo abak atm 4     20000.00      1
831107336668 atm wd 10630485 uyo                  10000.00      2
```

I have tried this line of code, but it always result to an error

`df.groupby(['cosine_group'])['amount'].mode()[['description', 'amount', 'cosine_group']]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `scipy.stats.mode`

- `GroupBy` on `cosine_group` which will result in multiple values against every group so you can apply aggregate function to keep only value in those columns against every group.
- Apply aggregate function `agg(lambda x: scipy.stats.mode(x)[0][0])` to `description` and `amount`
- `scipy.stats.mode(x)` returns tuple having list of most frequent value and list containing its frequency e.g `([20000.0], [4])`. But we want only most frequent value so we can get it by slices `[0][0]`
- `reset_index()` to remove cosine_group from `index`

```
import scipy.stats
out = df.groupby("cosine_group")[['description', 'amount']].agg(lambda x: scipy.stats.mode(x)[0][0]).reset_index()

print(out)

        cosine_group                              description    amount
0             0         0421209017073500 loan payment receipt    1625.95
1             1  419988664 atm wd 12140283 fcmb uyo abak atm 4  20000.00
2             2               816905417622 atm wd 10630481 uyo  10000.00
```

Comment: Are you sure? There is no description

Comment: agg will be applied on all columns.

Comment: Sure, but separately.

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani Thanks for your response, I need to understand what the `agg(lambda x: scipy.stats.mode(x)[0][0]` is really doing in the above expression

Comment: @jezrael description added.

Comment: @ChukwukaOkolie Please Check out the updated answer.

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani Is the most frequent value calculated based on the `amount` or `description`  ?

Just curious on what the **x** value is

Comment: Its calculated on the basis of `cosine_group`.  `agg(lambda x: scipy.stats.mode(x)[0][0])` will be applied on `[['description', 'amount']]` one by one.  Groups has already made on the basis of `cosine_group` But every group of `cosine_group` contains multiple values of the other columns right? so we need to apply some aggregate function to keep only one val for every defined columns . For the first time x will be `description` and the second time x will be `amount`.